# any third party providers for getting products information from all eCommerce affiliate api's

Tags: api, e-commerce, affiliate

We are working on application which has product search to get products information of product from all eCommerce websites. We have found that flipkart,amazon,ebay all are having their own affiliate api's to get product information. We are searching for third party api providers who gives information from all eCommerce websites. like price comparison api providers who give info from all eCommerce.

Answer (score 1):

I have built up a price comparison api that combines basic data from many sources into one list. It requires that you give it a upc and api keys for the providers that it supports. It will then go and give you back a list of products with their information including price.

The api so far supports Amazon, Ebay, Walmart, and BestBuy. It is written in .net but can be easly used to create a server that returns json data for a specific upc. If you need a differant provider you can just post a issue on the github.

It is called Gobble. Here is the link -  https://github.com/greatjack1/Gobble

Comment: I need your help. I want to develop a mobile app cross-platform which would enable price comparison between Ebay & Amazon and also get affiliate commission for each redirect which results in a purchase. ```Issue Number 1```: I am reading the T & C -> I see that I am not allowed to "d) must not emulate Amazon’s own shopping app 
 functionality;"   https://affiliate-program.amazon.co.uk/help/node/topic/GHBY6W8UPTEFD3ZX Does it mean I replicate the functionality if I show side by side 2 products and if user taps on it, then the user is redirected to Amazon?

Comment: ```Issue Number 2```: according  to Amazon Developer Docs, How many products can I promote in my app?  
 -> You can promote up to 1,000 products at a time in your app.  Is there something I am missing?  How could I do comparison shopping engine if I am limited to 1000 items? It's a little bit counter-intuitive .  https://developer.amazon.com/docs/mobile-associates/mas-faq.html